# iOS build a regular expression for use with NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

i've tried to read the apple documentation but i'll never use regular expression and i do not understand how to solve this matter.
I need to write a regular expression for check if the user has selected a string that match with this rules:
first letter could be s or S and it's optional
second chars could be a . (char dot) and it's optional
4 number digit could from 1 to 4 and must be always present
after the number could be present any single char from a-z and could be optional
after i can have a . (char dot) and it's optional
the last 2 must be a digit must be always 2 number and could be optional

i tried to write in this way

```
NSString *regexStr = @"(s|S)?(\\.)?(\\d+){,4}([a-z]?(\\.)?(\\d+){2}?";
```

but the console give this error

```
Error making regex: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 
"The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 2048.)" UserInfo=0x6d3e9b0  
{NSInvalidValue=(s|S)?(\.)?(\d+){,4}([a-z]?(\.)?(\d+){2}?}
```

Anyone could help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
(s|S)?(\.)?(\d){0,4}[a-z]?(\.)?(\d){2}?
```

You had an extra opening parenthesis that made the syntax invalid, and `+` signs after the `\d`s, that made the regexp accept infinite numbers of digits.

Regexpal is great for debugging regexps: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: Thanks geon for the help and for the good suggestions for the link.

Comment: I've tried and works in this way NSString* regexStr = @"(s|S)?(\.)?(\\d){2,4}[a-z]?[a-z]?(\.)?"; the problem is the last part of the expression, the last 2 optional digit. If i modified in this way NSString* regexStr = @"(s|S)?(\.)?(\\d){2,4}[a-z]?[a-z]?(\.)?(\\d){2}?"; with a code make like this s.10 do not match a result while with s.1000 number of match is 1. Seems that the last option add other 2 digit to the mask but i need to modified in this way: validate the last 2 number only if is present the last dot char. is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Oh, you still need to escape the backslashes when typing it in as a string: @"(s|S)?(\\.)?(\\d){0,4}[a-z]?(\\.)?(\\d){2}?".

Comment: Thanks geon works! The exact one for my case if someone need as example is (s|S)?(\\.)?(\\d){2,4}[a-z]?(\\.)?(\\d){2}?